# Generic ParamSpec on Python 3.9

Tags: python, typing

The following is correct in Python 3.10, but not 3.9:

```
from typing import Generic
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec("P")


class Foo(Generic[P]):
    pass


foo: Foo[[int, str]] = Foo()
```

Running the above triggers a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got [<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>].
```

What must I do to get this piece of code to run in Python 3.9?

I get it that [ParamSpec](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#parameter-specification-variables) is a 3.10 feature. But [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) is supposed to make the code backward-compatible, right? I'm guessing that I must change the syntax of `Foo[[int, str]]` to something else, but what?

Related discussion: https://github.com/python/typing/discussions/908

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `Foo[int]`, regardless of the Python version?

Comment: Good point. I'm actually trying to define an instance of `Foo` where the ParamSpec is multiple arguments, so my piece of code was simplified too much. I'll amend it.

Comment: From the linked pypi page: "ParamSpec and Concatenate will not work with get_args and get_origin. Certain PEP 612 special cases in user-defined Generics are also not available." - I'm not intimately familiar with PEP 612 but this might be such a special case. Either that or you've found a bug / edge case which is not mentioned in the typing_extension limitations.

Comment: Seems like a pretty standard use case to me... The fact that the code is not working at runtime does not indicate that typing_extensions is at fault, but rather that the syntax is not supported by Python 3.9. I'm wondering whether typing_extensions has a solution for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to pass a string as the type definition:

```
foo: "Foo[[int, str]]" = Foo()
```

Alternatively, the ["unsightly double brackets"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#user-defined-generic-classes) can be removed:

```
foo: "Foo[int, str]" = Foo()
```